# Moving subproject files and updating links in master project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am working in MS Project and frequently move schedules from a share drive to my computer, manipulate and run macros on them, then copy them back up to the share drive.

Generally if I copy all of the subprojects with the Master project at one time the links to the subprojects will update to the destination folder (the one on my computer.) Occasionally I do this and the links do not update, so the Master Schedule is still pointing to the files on the share drive.  This causes problems with the macro I then run on it.  I have not been able to find anything in forums about this problem.

Has anyone come across this problem? Is there a setting somewhere that is getting changed? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've come across this problem.

The most reliable way of copying a master schedule and all it's sub projects without creating the duplicate links is to:

1. Select all the files on the share drive
2. Right click and send them to a zip file
3. Move this zip file to your local drive
4. Right click on the zip file and extract all

Then do the same in reverse once you've run your macros. This should reliably copy the master/sub project files with the correct links, without creating the erroneous links you've seen.